# How do I link UNNotificationServiceExtension swift code to the app?

Tags: swift, xcode

First off, I'm using the latest Xcode, I've added the UNNotificationServiceExtension which works beautifully when I test it by attaching my iPhone to macbook.

You know how on the top left of Xcode, there is 2 drop downs, and on the right side of it there the device-drop down?

**Scenario A:**

On the left drop down: the app name

On the right drop down: my iphone

Result :UNNotificationServiceExtension does not get called

**Scenario B:**

On the left drop down: the extension name

On the right drop down: my iphone

Result :UNNotificationServiceExtension gets called

Now I've published by app to the app store and UNNotificationServiceExtension is not getting called so I'm thinking my build did not include the extension.

Am I supposed to the link the extension and the main app together somehow, or compile a different way?